# Fail to include Nicedit Rich Text Editor in BPopup box. The Orientation mixed up

Tags: jquery, popup, textarea, nicedit, bpopup

I am new to Jquery and trying to use it in my project.

I got a page, using bPopup. In the bPopup, I include nicedit in the pop up div. But the rich text toolbar seems to be screw up. Any one know how to fix it?

Below are the code and example of the output.

[image]

The toolbar of nicedit seems to be mixed up the orientation. But when I use the nicedit in a normal webpage (without popup) it work flawlessly.

index.php----

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> <!--This is for the interface-->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://dinbror.dk/downloads/jquery.bpopup-0.7.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> 

</head>
<body>

<button>POP IT UP</button>

<div style = "position: relative; display:none; width:500px; height:500px; background-color:white; border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; box-shadow: 0 0 25px 5px #999;">

<textarea id = "area1" name = "area1" cols = "40">
This is the default text in text box.
</textarea>
<script>
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    new nicEditor().panelInstance('area1');

});
</script>
</div>



<h1 style = "background-color : white">This is the content
   <script>
    // Semicolon (;) to ensure closing of earlier scripting
    // Encapsulation
    // $ is assigned to jQuery
    ;(function($) {
         // DOM Ready
        $(function() {

            // Binding a click event
            // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
            $('button').on('click', function(e) {

                // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
                e.preventDefault();

                // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
                $('div').bPopup({
                    position: ['auto', 'auto'], //x, y
                    modal: true, //A transperant black layer behind
                    positionStyle: 'fixed', //Fix the popup in the middle
                    scrollbar: false,

                });

            });

        });

    })(jQuery);
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```